# Displaying user.name via user.ID | 2 Tables, need to join, PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables, one is a table for users, another one is for microposts.
They have one column in common, the user_id.

```
> table "users":

id   name    email            created_at       updated_at
--------------------------------------------------------
  1    John  a@gmail.com       DD-MM-YY|H:M      DD-MM-YY|H:M
  2    Mike  e@gmail.com       DD-MM-YY|H:M      DD-MM-YY|H:M
  3    Duke  i@gmail.com       DD-MM-YY|H:M      DD-MM-YY|H:M
  4    Queen o@gmail.com       DD-MM-YY|H:M      DD-MM-YY|H:M
> table "microposts"

id   content          user_id
------------------------------
7     "First Post"      1
9     "Second Post"     2
6     "Third Post"      3
10    "Last Post"       4
```

I want to display the last post created(DONE), with the posts' creator username.
I know I have to Inner Join these two tables, i don't know how to do it in php.

EXAMPLE:

Quenn
"Last Post"

Comment: You do an INNER JOIN in SQL, not PHP. `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id`.

Comment: How do I use it then, in php ??

Comment: You're asking how to execute a SQL query from within PHP? You can use either PDO or mysqli to make a connection to the database and run the query. There are large sections of the PHP manual devoted to those libraries, and free online tutorials, blog posts etc by the million giving examples. It's not a topic you should need to ask about, unless you tried something and have a specific error which you can't find anything out about online.

Comment: P.S. If you just want to get the most recent post and the exact fields you mentioned, then try `SELECT users.name, microposts.content FROM users INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id ORDER BY microposts.id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: I would recommend https://phpdelusions.net/pdo as a very good and thorough tutorial, teaching good techniques. https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/ is a slightly gentler one, but also thorough.

Comment: Check my update pls :)

Comment: I did it ! Thanks to you !! No need to check the update, I just did it :) Thx <333